# Dataset value going in catch if not greater than 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I am filling some values in `Dataset` but when I returns no rows, I have made an else part for those returning values less than 0.

Here is the code

```
ds = GetCircleDetails(XY, txtSapIdNHQCircle.Text);

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    strState = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["R4GSTATENAME"].ToString();

                    if (Save(0))
                    {
                        BindDetails(false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "checkRdValueForSingle('Please enter valid Lat/Long to submit the details')", true);
                    string latLongMes = "alert('Please enter valid Lat/Long to submit the details')";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", latLongMes, true);
                    txtLatNHQCircle.Value = "";
                    txtLongNHQCircle.Value = "";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "checkRdValueForSingle('')", true);
                    return;
                }
                if (lblStateNHQCircle.Text != strState)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "checkRdValueForSingle('The entered lat/long is out of the existing State i.e., so could not save the record.');", true);
                    return;
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                if (Save(0))
                {
                    BindDetails(false);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(Save(0))
        {
            BindDetails(false);
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Error occured: Could not save change request data.');", true);
        ErrorLog.Save(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "ChangeRequestDetails - btnSave_Click", CurrentUserName);
        throw ex;
    }
```

And the function of `GetCircleDetails(XY, txtSapIdNHQCircle.Text);` is below

```
public DataSet GetCircleDetails(string xyCoordinate, string sapid)
{
    string ConnectionStringWFM = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringCR"].ConnectionString;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringWFM);

    string strStoreProcedure = "GET_CIRCLENAME_XYPOINT";

    try
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strStoreProcedure, oraConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_XYCORDINATE", xyCoordinate));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_SAPID", sapid));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("OUTR4GSTATENAME", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("OUTALLDETAILS", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
        if (oraConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) oraConn.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {

    }        
}
```

PLease suggest why its going in `catch` instead of `else`

**update**

I am getting error as

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Error occured: Could not save change request data.');", true);`

But I should get it as

`string latLongMes = "alert('Please enter valid Lat/Long to submit the details')";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", latLongMes, true);`

Comment: Start by handling the error instead of throwing a new one. It might give you a hint as to what the error might be...

Comment: @VDWWD: how you are telling, please suggest

Comment: I suggest you handle the error and read the error message. That should tell you what the error is instead just posting all the code here and asking for a solution. If you post the error it is much easier to help you.

Comment: @VDWWD: yes, I m handling that in else part right ?? if not what is wrong with my code. ?

Comment: @VDWWD: Updated the question, have a look

Answer (score 0):

To check dataset is empty or not you have to check null and tables count.You could use `if(ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 )`

Comment: so will it go in else part ??

Answer (score -1):

if you get error in

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```

Add this Code

```
 Responce.Write("<script>alert('Your Text Here');</script>")
```